# Why when rotating a camera using a key press when the camera is facing an object it's shaking/stuttering?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this script attached to the Main Camera.
For example when the camera is start facing the terrain when rotating it's shaking/stuttering then it's continue fine. It seems like when the camera first facing an object if the camera is moving to a object or moving near other objects it's shaking/stuttering then continue fine.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpinObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float smooth = 1f;
    private Quaternion targetRotation;
    void Start()
    {
        targetRotation = transform.rotation;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            targetRotation *= Quaternion.AngleAxis(1, Vector3.up);
        }
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, 10 * smooth * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

I tried also LateUpdate.
I'm not sure when is the problem.

Comment: I tried to create a new empty clean project and added the script to the camera same thing. When the camera is rotating and then facing first time the terrain there is a short stuttering then it's continue fine.

Comment: What happens if you use GetKeyUp (will only trigger once per press) instead of GetKey (will trigger multiple times, for as many frames as you hold down the key, even if briefly)?